# Eclipse – Hibernate Tools – New connection profile

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I’m trying to add new connection profile to Eclipses Hibernate tolls. But in configuration window I can specify only SID, but my database uses Service name. What can I do in this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Thin Driver takes only SID in a New Connection Profile.

You need to select ***Other Driver*** instead of ***Oracle Thin Driver*** in *New Driver Definition.*

That will give you an option to give whole url in which you can give *service name* instead of *sid.*

*eg) **URL :  jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.72.11:1521/serviceName***